# function works after the second click (as3)

Tags: actionscript-3

I have two mocieclip  on stage (plus1 which colours 8 squares and minus1 which give the original colour to the squares). If i colour some squares (not all of them) and try to give them their original colour with minus1, fucntion starts after the second click and if i try to continue to colour the rest squares  fucntion again starts after the second click. I can' t understand why. Can you please help me find whats wrong? Here is my code.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;


plus1.buttonMode=true;
minus1.buttonMode=true;


var nextSquare:MovieClip = square1;

var squares:Array = [square1, square2, square3, square4, square5, square6, square7, square8];

var myColorTransform:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();


plus1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changeColour);

function changeColour(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    myColorTransform.color = 0x519596;
    nextSquare.transform.colorTransform = myColorTransform;

    var index = squares.indexOf(nextSquare);
    if (index < squares.length - 1) {
        nextSquare = squares[index + 1];
    } else {
        trace('we are done');
    }   
}

minus1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, reversecolour);

function reversecolour(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    nextSquare.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform();

       var index = squares.indexOf(nextSquare);
    if (index >0) {
        nextSquare = squares[index - 1];
    } else {
        trace('we are done');
    }   
}
```

Comment: Since we don't see where the squares are created, it's hard to know what the problem is. Check your frames, and instance names and make sure you don't have anything happening out of order.  (like assigning nextSquare before square1 exists.)

Comment: It can be. You should put each square on it's own layer, and make sure the instance names are correct.

Comment: I put each square in its own layer but the problem persist. Instance names are correct. I even try with squares (fill and stroke) but the problem continues.

Comment: How many frames do you have?

Comment: I have only one frame.

Comment: Put a trace in your fuction, when you click the first time, does it trace out? or does it never enter the function?

Comment: i trace index and i click plus1 3 times and from the array i trace 0,1,2 (square1, square2 andsquare3 were colored). When i click minus1 I trace 3, 2, 1. It goes up one and then starts to take squares in their original colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are working on the "next square" with your minus button, when what you really want to change is the "current square".   When you reverse a color change, you want to change the color of the square you just changed, not the "nextSquare" that you are about to change.

So, I would change your code as follows:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;


plus1.buttonMode=true;
minus1.buttonMode=true;


var nextSquare:MovieClip = square1;
var currentSquare:MovieClip = null;
var squares:Array = [square1, square2, square3, square4, square5, square6, square7, square8];

var myColorTransform:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();


plus1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changeColour);

function changeColour(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    myColorTransform.color = 0x519596;
    nextSquare.transform.colorTransform = myColorTransform;
    currentSquare = nextSquare;
    var index = squares.indexOf(nextSquare);
    if (index < squares.length - 1) {
        nextSquare = squares[index + 1];
    } else {
        trace('we are done');
    }   
}

minus1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, reversecolour);

function reversecolour(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    currentSquare.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform();
    nextSquare =  currentSquare;
       var index = squares.indexOf(currentSquare);
    if (index >0) {
        currentSquare = squares[index - 1];
    } else if (index == -1){
         trace("First change a colour");
    } 
    else {
        trace('we are done');
    }   
}
```

Comment: That's it! You solve it! Well done! Thank you. I did an addition at minus1 function to work correctly  nextSquare =  currentSquare;
Thank you!